# How to use jquery VALUE in an ajax success function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I cannot use value `div name` in fourth-last line

I want to use div name in Ajax function in `$("divname").html(data);`

```
$('.edit').click(function() {
    var object = $(this);
    var rowvalue = object.attr('id');
    var rowvalue_array = rowvalue.split('_');
    var id = rowvalue_array[1];
    var comment = $('#comment_'+id).val();
    var divname = '#'+id;
    var varData = 'id='+id+'&comment='+comment;
    console.log(varData);
    $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "edit_field.php",
        data: varData,
        success: function(data) {
            $("divname").html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;   
});
```

Comment: Thanks Srivi. Can you help above problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code..

```
$.ajax ({
               type: "POST",
               url: "edit_field.php",
               data: varData,

               success: function(data) {
                    $(divname).html(data);
               }
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your line as below :

```
$(divname).html(data);
```

remove quata (")

**divname** is variable
or you can use as below :

```
$("#"+id).html(data);
```

Comment: Worked Vijay ji! Thanking you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax ({
               type: "POST",
               url: "edit_field.php",
               data: varData,

               success: function() {
                    $("divname").html($(this).data);
               }
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you accessing the element by id when u have the element.....try

```
$(object).html(data);
```